# Android detect selected tab and change ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs

Hi i have an an ActionBar that contains a TabBar and on each tab i want to change the actionbar title/icon based on which tab is selected. How do i detect which tab i'm on and run an if statement for example `if tab = tab1 then set actionbar title`?

heres my activity

```
         ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
         actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
         getActionBar().setTitle("");
         getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ab_logo);
         getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
         actionbar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee")));


         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, null);


         ActionBar.Tab Tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_1);
         ActionBar.Tab Tab2 = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_2);
         ActionBar.Tab Tab3 = actionbar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView);
         ActionBar.Tab Tab4 = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_4);
         ActionBar.Tab Tab5 = actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_5);



         Fragment Fragment1 = new Fragment1();
         Fragment Fragment2 = new Fragment2();
         Fragment Fragment3 = new Fragment3();
         Fragment Fragment4 = new Fragment4();
         Fragment Fragment3 = new Fragment5();


         Tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment1));
         Tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment2));
         Tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment3));
         Tab4.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment4));
         Tab5.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment5));

         actionbar.addTab(Tab1);
         actionbar.addTab(Tab2);
         actionbar.addTab(Tab3);
         actionbar.addTab(Tab4);
         actionbar.addTab(Tab5);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

}
```

heres my TabListener Class

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;
    public Context c;
    public ActionBar actionbar;

    public TabListener(Fragment fragment, Context con) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.c = con;
    }   



    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

}
```

Comment: what you need to do is , set flags on the visibility of each fragment. ex: create some constant class and define some flags(as required , ie no of tabs=no of flags) in that constant class now when fragment"A" is visible make that flag true, do same for other tabs and change there respective flags. at last depending upon the flags show or hide the items in your actionbar in your main activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do this in your `onTabSelected` method

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 1:
            actionbar.setTitle("new title");
            actionbar.setIcon(iconDrawable);
            break;
        case 2:
            actionbar.setTitle("new title");
            actionbar.setIcon(iconDrawable);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in each fragment:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;
```

in onActivityCreated:

```
actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

in fragment onCreateView method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}
```

then in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) method

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    // Clear old menu.
    menu.clear();
    // Inflate new menu.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_fragment_menu, menu);
    // Set actionbar title and icon.
    actionBar.setTitle("your fragment title");
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fragment);
}
```

Hope this answer help you.